# Show all numbers from 1 to n increasing from 1 to 1 where n is entered by the user at a prompt

Tags: javascript

I´m learning javascript, so please be gentle with me.
About my question above, this is the code I made, the difficult part for me is related to the prompt, if the task were "show all the numbers from 1 to 10 using a while", I know how to do it.

```js
var x = Number(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
var contador = 1;

while (contador <= x) {

  console.log(contador + x);

  contador++;
}
```

Comment: You dont need to add `contador + x`. You can just `console.log(contador);`

Comment: Actually, `console.log(contador);`

Comment: The prompt is working fine. Just as others commented you should not add x to your log statement. What is your problem with the prompt?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show number from 1 to user entered number then why you add x in console log try below code it will show 1 to x,

```
 var x = Number(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
 var contador = 1;

 while (contador<=x) {

   console.log(contador);

   contador++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If u need using while do this:

```js
 var x = Number(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
 var contador = 1;

 while (contador<=x) {
   console.log(contador++); //return number and increase it for next loop
 }
```

But the best and fastest solution is this:

```js
var x = Number(prompt("Ingrese un número"));
for(var i = 1; i <= x; i++)
   console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've understood the `while` part.

Here is what the `prompt` part does:

`prompt` creates a prompt window (like an alert window) which asks for user input. The user input, by default, is a string. 
So we we need to convert it into a number. we use `Number(someStrongValue)` to convert this user input to a number.

```
Number("1") == 1
Number("a") == NaN
```

If you didn't convert the string to a number, you may end up with an infinite loop, or the loop may not even run.

If the user enters a string in prompt, Number will return NaN. 
and any `number < NaN` is false. Hence, your loop won't run (and no infinite loop)

You can read more about prompt here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: Thank you all for your reply, few hours later than I asked this, I resolved this, of course I read all the replies today, they were also helpful. I will continue learning, and probably do more questions.